# Odoo 15: Tree view listing all base model instances created through inheritance

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-view

I'd like to use classic inheritance. Let's say A and B inherit from BASE.

I'd like to be able to create instances of A and instances of B, and all should be visible in the same list/tree view.

I naively created a tree view using the BASE model, and surprisingly it doesn't retrieve instances of children of the BASE class.

To me that's a basic case of inheritance, but it seems tricky with Odoo, or maybe I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: That's possible with the ["delegation inheritance"](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension), where every submodel will also create an instance (row in database) of the base model if used correctly.

Comment: In Odoo 15 there is only one really good example: Account moves. In the account moves table you will find data from "normal" account moves, bank statement lines and payments. The last two use the delegation inheritance.

Comment: @CZoellner Thank you for your comment! When I read that part of the documentation earlier, I dismissed "delegation inheritance" when I read "When using Delegation, the model has one instead of is one, turning the relationship in a composition instead of inheritance". The example given also didn't look like something I could use. But now I start to see how it could be used in my case.

Comment: @CZoellner I had a quick look in the code, and installed the "account" module, hoping to also maybe find some tree view that would unify the three models, and even open the form specific to the model when a line is clicked, like I try to do. But either I missed it, or it's still for me to figure out...

Comment: You have to install the full accounting which IIRC has to be `account_accountant` of enterprise to see a list of all account moves.

Comment: @CZoellner I probably didn't look hard enough, but I didn't find what I was looking for in `account_accountant`. But I used the `inherits`, and indeed that creates both a Parent and a Child instance. However, it works by just adding a reference to the Parent instance into the table of Child instances. So, I don't see how it would be possible to open the correct form for the Child instance from the tree view of the Parent instance.

Comment: @CZoellner Another requirement I have is that the tree view of the Parent instance has a column showing the type of Child the Parent is referring to. I thought I would just override a method of the parent in each child which method would return a translated string. But that seems impossible as well. I might have to make the parent type "conscious" of each of its children types somehow, which is not a really nice practice in OOP terms...

Comment: Okay something i did not mention was that only the "base" fraction or the inherited fields are in the list view for all. So a full list (and form view) of all you child instances is IIRC not possible. The delegation inheritance is only a alternative, possibly not for your requirements.

Comment: @YugoAmaryl You can use [SQL Views](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/tutorials/dashboards.html?highlight=sql#sql-views) with a list view, you can also override the `_onOpenRecord` function in the list controller to open the corresponding record form view